# howto loopthrough json in javascript/jquery and read data properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json returned from the serverlet as follow:

```
{
"0": {
    "id": "1252380",
    "text": "This whole #BundyRanch thing stinks to high hell. Can it be a coincidence that Harry Reid n his son have a financial interest in this land?",
    "date": "2014-05-31",
    "name": "Code Green Hackathon",
    "url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/424023521040166913/1dAg1g_r_normal.jpeg",
    "username": "t.getScreenName()"
},
"1": {
    "id": "1252378",
    "text": "Harry Reid threatens private property in America http://t.co/uBX7lau0EP via @worldnetdaily",
    "date": "2014-05-31",
    "name": "Murray Leismeister",
    "url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000559954056/724415b96df3a22d2a9cc6e2b90052dc_normal.jpeg",
    "username": "t.getScreenName()"
}
```

}

and in javascript I do this to read my json:

```
       for(var item in jsresult)
            {
                alert(item);
            }
```

I expect to see two alert showing 0 and then 1 but I dont. Instead I get six alert showing 0,1 0,1 0,1 respectively, I checked the server and I am sure that the only jason returns is the one that I posted above. So something is wrong with my javascript code. Can anyone help?(I am so confused)

Update:

Here is my ajax call

```
$.get(getServletURLTweet(), {
            timeRange : tRange,
            entities : enIDs,
            topics:tpIDs
        }, function(results) {
            jsresult = jQuery.parseJSON(results);
            for(var item in jsresult)
            {
                alert(item);
            }});
```

Comment: Do you call this code 3 times perhaps?

Comment: what is the output of console.log(jsresult);

Comment: do you get the same error using jQuerys `$.each()` ?

Comment: @Halcyon No it is just one call

Comment: @xcezzz I checked the console it is exactly the same as I posted above(I mean the json)

Comment: @HamedMinaee try `console.log` instead of `alert`, it gives you better debug info. Maybe the input isn't what you expect it to be.

Comment: @Halcyon when I do console.log there is no problem but when I loop through jason I get that duplicate

Comment: @Nano I never used that now I am trying to make it with your approach but I cannot create the for loop with $.each properly can you help me?

Comment: @HamedMinaee `$.each(jsresult,function(key,value){alert(key);})`

Comment: @Nano no not working:(

Comment: maybe you are making three ajax calls? I dont know, what it could be otherwise.

Comment: @HamedMinaee Have you tested in different browsers: IE, Chrome, FF to see if you get different results?

Comment: Msxml2.XMLHTTP and Microsoft.XMLHTTP fire the onreadystatechange event and sequence the readyState codes a little differently.  one returns multiple times which needs to be handled.  JQuery should handle this.  Worth checking any way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
var data = [ 
 {"Id": 10, "PageName": "home"}, 
 {"Id": 11, "PageName": "about"}, 
 {"Id": 12, "PageName": "more"}
];

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
 alert(data[i].PageName);
});​
```